# sending automatic emails by google script

Tags: function, email, google-sheets, sendmail, automatic-updates

I am trying to set up an automatic email notification system in google spreadsheet.
I would like to send these emails from a specific sheet, name is "contacts".
How can I set up a script what is using this sheet instead of the first sheet?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use a sheets Add-on called formMule. You can select the sheet from which you want to send your emails. Go to the Add-ons menu, and search for "formMule".

FormMule allows you to select the sheet, send on a condition, send up to 12 different email templates. You can send at a specific time as well.

I use it all the time. Let me know if you have any questions about how to use it.